# Equals sign (and others) in constant

Tags: coding-style

I am currently refactoring a codebase inherited from another developer. In several classes, i found constants that contained the symbols =, ? and & (and others). They are used to build URLs, like so:

```
class SomeClass {
    private static final String EQUALS = "=";
    private static final String AMPERSAND = "&";
    private static final String QUESTION_MARK = "?";
    private static final String FORWARD_SLASH = "/";
    // ...

    public String getSomeURL() {
        return ProjectConstants.BASE_URL + entityName + FORWARD_SLASH + 
             anotherName + QUESTION_MARK + parameterName + EQUALS + parameterValue;
    }
}
```

I do not see the benefit of this. What is the reason for this style instead of just writing `variable + '/' + variable + "?parameterName=" + parameterValue`?

Answer (score 3):

The constants are useful, but poorly named. If they're used in URL construction, they should be named like this:

```
private static final String PARAMETER_ASSIGNMENT = "=";
private static final String PARAMETER_SEPARATOR = "&";
private static final String QUERY_INTRODUCER = "?";
private static final String PATH_SEPARATOR = "/";
```

That way, their names will refer to their *semantics* (which they should) and not to their *contents* (the whole point is to *abstract* away from the contents!).

The code of `getSomeURL()` will then much more directly signal what it really does:

```
public String getSomeURL() {
    return ProjectConstants.BASE_URL + entityName +
           PATH_SEPARATOR + anotherName +
           QUERY_INTRODUCER +
               parameterName + PARAMETER_ASSIGNMENT + parameterValue;
}
```

Comment: That is more semantic, yes. But i still have a much harder time reading it than with just the inline characters/strings.

Comment: @marstato The problem is that URLs are so well-known that the constants' values are unlikely to ever change. But if you ever find yourself adapting that class to provide its data in format other than URLs, the benefit will be clear. The whole point is: a constant should be named whenever you can give a better name for it than just its value. And you *can* in this case.

Comment: Thats a valid reason. But it doesnt cover for the loss in readability imo, though.

Comment: @marstato Just as hint: your own wording about stuff being "imo" ... kinda implies that your question isn't exactly great. SO ... not about opinions (but maybe I am just complaining because nobody upvoted my answer yet)

Comment: @Angew this is a comment because it is an opinion :)

Answer (score 0):

I think there are not *any* deep technical reasons here

The only *little* thing I see: they make typos like "==" less likely to happen, as EQUALS + EQUALS is obviously more obvious to spot.

On the other hand, that shouldn't really matter in reality; because in reality you would be calling *helper* methods to build those URLs anyway. So, once you got the helpers right, few chances of ever having typos in that "generated" content.

But even then I would not be using String constants but char values.

Comment: Typo prevention is actually a good point. Though, i agree to what you say: helper methods should take care of that.